# I need to terminate input sequence without entering any special value, just by pressing empty enter

Tags: java

Tried using hasNextInt() but it won't terminate unless an invalid input is entered.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int total=0; int temp;
        while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            temp=sc.nextInt();
            if(temp>0&&temp<17)total +=200;
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input"); break;
            }
        } System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Try `nextLine()` and parse the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = null;

    do {
        input = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("do your logic here, input was "+temp);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("invalid input, terminating");
            break;
        }
    } while (!"".equals(input));

    System.out.println("--- end ---");
```

Or this

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        if ("".equals(input)) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("do your logic here, input was " + temp);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("invalid input, terminating");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("--- end ---");
```